# Navigating to a Razor Page from a C# Class File

Tags: c#, events, razor

## Problem

I'm developing a website using Razor Pages (.cshtml) which asyncronously runs a Console Application using `Process.Start()` when a user clicks a button. I've wired an Event handler to the `Exited` event of the process which is called when the process exits. Starting the process and handling the exited event are both done in one C# class file (.cs). When the exited event is handled, the ExitCode of the process is evaluated to decide what message to display back to the user.

Currently I'm attempting to navigate directly to the View, which contains code to process and display the url parameter. This navigation fails every time.

## Attempts

I have deduced that the parameter isn't the problem by removing it entirely and attempting to simply redirect to a page.

When I try `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Folder/File.cshtml)` I get a

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I try passing `HttpContext.Current` from the Controller that made the initial `Process.Start()` call to the C# class file to use for the `Response.Redirect()` I get an

> ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

## Additional

The fact that the event is triggered by a process is likely irrelevant, as the core issue seems to be redirecting from a C# class file to a Razor Page. My goal is to update a Razor View once the Process completes to inform the user of success or failure.

Comment: I am not familiar with ASP.NET Web Pages. But the fundamentals of the web do not change - you can't have the server redirect the client outside of a request/response context. You would need the user to manually perform a refresh (thus causing a new request) or have AJAX or websockets communicating asynchronously back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this in a web-compliant way, I'd propose to use one of the following approaches:

#### if the process that is started is very short lived:

when starting the process in a request, wait for the process to finish before returning the request to the client.

### if the process takes several seconds to complete:

In this case, using SignalR is a good option as it supports pushing messages from the server to a client. See this [link](https://www.asp.net/signalr) for details and samples on SignalR.

Basically, you'd start processing the item when the request arrives at the server. Return a view to the client that informs the user that the item is being processed. Push a message to the client once the item has been processed.